# Integral and unit of measurement

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, physics

Is there a kind of "formalism" which define how unit measures come out from integration?

An example: given a point $P(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ there is the concept of mass $m$ associated to this point. Mass is measured in $\text{kg,g,lb,...}$ I indicate the generic unite measure of the mass $[m]$. Now, there is also the concept of density of mass $\rho(x,y,z)$ which is a (scalar) function which represents "mass per unit volume", or also $\frac{[m]}{[s]^3}$ (where $[s]$ is the unit measure of space), *e.g.* if we take a constant density over a volume, to know the mass of the volume it suffices to multiply density $\rho$ with volume $V$. The effect of this multiplication is coherent with unit measures involved.

Now, in general for non-constant density function, one needs to integrate the function over the volume to know mass:

$m=\int_V \rho(x,y,z)\text{d}\tau$ where $\tau$ is the volume element.

Now, integrals are pure mathematical objects, how can I relate the fact that an integral is not only *(naively) "a product of the integrand for the measure of the space of integration"* with the fact that, in the end, there will be $[m]=\frac{[m]}{[s]^3} [s]^3$

Now, naively I can argument something like this $\int_{[s^3]} \frac{[m]}{[s]^3} \text{d}([s^3])$, but the integrand is constant so $\frac{[m]}{[s]^3} \int_{[s^3]} \text{d}([s]^3)=[m]$. But here there is no mathematical formalism, only a naive thought about such an "integral of unit measures" sounds to me.

Is there actually an ad-hoc formal argument for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the simplest way to formalise it is to write dimensionful quantities as a product of a dimenionless number and a constant dimensionful parameter. In this way you get e.g. $\rho=\bar{\rho}\times [\rho]$, with $\bar\rho$ dimensionless and $[\rho]$ the appropriate unit. Now if ypou change your unit of density, you get a rescaling $[\rho]\to \lambda [\rho]$ which you can absorb into the dimensionless prefactor. Of course, this is just a slightly fanciefied way of writing a quantity as value times unit.

The same trick works for the integration measure - at least for Riemannian integrals, the measure is a limit of small actual volume elements, and the $\text{d}v$ rescales if you change the units.

Now you can just pull the "units" out of the integral, since they are constant, and you're left with a dimensionless integral times some product of units of the correct dimension.